# s(A) + s(B) = ? Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$A:= \{ x^2 | x \in (2,3\sqrt{2}] , x \in \mathbb{R} \textrm{ and } x^2 \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

$$B:= \{ x^3 | x \in (-2\sqrt[3]{3},3] , x \in \mathbb{R} \textrm{ and } x^3 \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

---

> s(A) + s(B) = ?

s(A) is number of elements of A set. 
For example if $\ A = \{a,b,c\} $

```
s(A) = 3
```

Comment: I fixed the TeX for you.

Comment: Thank you Willie :) I hope question is clear, now .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $x \in (2, 3\sqrt{2}]$, what can $x^2$ be? It must be

$$ 2^2 = 4 < x^2 \leq 18 = (3\sqrt{2})^2 $$

So $A$ comprises of all integers ($x^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$) bigger than 4 and less-than-or-equal-to 18. There are 14 of them.

---

Given $x \in (-2\sqrt[3]{3}, 3]$, you similarly find that

$$ -24 < x^3 \leq 27 $$

which tells you that there are $27 - (-24) = 51$ elements in $B$

---

Add them together you get $s(A) + s(B) = 65$.

Comment: +1.  It is as easy as that.  Meanwhile $s(A \cup B) = 51$ and $s(A \cap B) = 14$.  I don't really see why someone would want to calculate this sort of thing.

Comment: but x must be a $\mathbb{R} $ , so x can be $\ 2\sqrt{3} $ for example. And $\ (2\sqrt{3})^2 = 12 $ and $\ 12 \in \mathbb{Z} $

Comment: @Henry: This is surely an exercise in understanding and manipulating basic notation in how things are defined: using $\{... \| ... \}$, implicit definitions $x^2$, and using close and open bounds to ranges.

Comment: @Mitch: Perhaps you are right.  I would have been happier if it asked for $s(A)$ and $s(B)$ separately, but it was asking for the sum which made me dubious.

Comment: @Eray Alakese: Willie Wong has counted 12 as an element of $A$ (and, incidentally, also of $B$).

Comment: @Henry, he counted only integers.

Comment: @Eray Alakese: the definitions $A:= \{x^2\ldots$ implies that the elements of A are the squares, which are required to be integers.